# Subtract a number of 2nd column

Tags: matlab

I am pretty new with Matlab. So here is the stupid question:
I have a data file, such as 'data.txt' and the file contents look like

```
0 -2.176438e-11
1 -7.751301e-12
2 6.332895e-12
3 2.763174e-11
4 2.061617e-11
5 4.390593e-11
6 4.734998e-10
7 3.424720e-10
```

and so on. What I want to do, I want to subtract a single number '6.332895e-12' from each row of the second column and print the output with the same 1st column and edited second column to a new file. Could any body please help me in writing the code? 
Once I know how to subtract a single number from each row of the second column, I believe, I can generalize the code to subtract different numbers from each row of the 2nd column.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a two column matrix `A`, and you want to modify the second column by subtracting a number `n` and keep the first column, you can do this,

```
A = [A(:,1) A(:,2)-n];
```

Answer (score 1):

Go fancy - use something like `bsxfun(@minus,A,[0,1])`